# Set size on post_thumbnail and lightbox

Tags: php, html, wordpress, thumbnails

I need to set lightbox and size with the post_thumbnail function.

I have this code implemented on my site http://pastebin.com/UhA1UxYv

How can I set a size like 355px X 236px and this large image add the rel to open in lightbox? or thickbox

I know that the function to set size is `array(355,236)`, but I don't know how implemented this in the code.

Answer (score 1):

like this i think

```
wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id(), array(355,236))
```

Answer (score 0):

It is very simple, use this instead will save your time and server load.

http://code.google.com/p/timthumb/